# How do I get a 2D array applying np.apply_along_axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to get the distance between a point and every point into the NumPy array and append the result into the same array but in a new column.

The shape of the original NumPy array (array_) is (2,3) and the shape of the resulting value after applying np.apply_along_axis is (2,), but what I really want to get is (2,2)

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
 
 _get_distance(array_=data, point=(-68.8814251389133716,-18.1163441921912174))
```

Input

```
In [213], in _get_distance(array_, point)

  def _get_distance(array_, point):
      xa = point[0]
      ya = point[1]
      6 distance_func = lambda coordi: math.sqrt((coordi[0] - xa)**2 + (coordi[1] - ya)**2)
      point_distance = np.apply_along_axis(distance_func, 1, array_[:, 1:3])
      np.append(array_, point_distance, axis=0)


ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

Comment: Don't use `np.append`, and don't use this `apply`.  They don't make your iteration any better or faster.

Comment: ok, what is a better option? map maybe?

Comment: I solved the problem by doing this:

distance_func = lambda coordi: math.sqrt((coordi[0] - xa)**2 + (coordi[1] - ya)**2)
    point_distance = np.array([[distance_func(row)] for row in array_[:, 1:3]]) 

    return np.concatenate((array_, point_distance), axis=1)